# Firebase dynamic link short url is not working while redirecting one domain to another domain in firebase hosting (Long link is working good)

Tags: url, dynamic, hyperlink, short

I had redirect my new domain to old domain in firebase hosting, Everything fine in this except dynamic short url is not working, it shows dynamic url is not found, Long url is working good, Please help me on this